# Both 64-bit and 32-bit support for development purposes

Tags: 64-bit, programming, 32-bit, development

I'm looking for directions to complete in the most convenient way (well at least without lots of troubles) set up as in subject.

I need (probably):

- 64 bit platform for running 64-bit Vmware Win7 image (ideally 64-bit as maybe it can be pulled off with 32-bit)
- however on it (platform) musts to be able to compile 32-bit code and some internal development tools and libs (including some commercial debugger) and run those with different than original libs (like switching to custom-build 32-bit lib instead of native 64-bit)
- it (platform) needs to be able to crosscompile ARM builds with 32-bit version of tools and libs
- Java (probably both 64-bit and 32-bit)  - as some internal tools are build around Eclipse

I'm looking for directions how to set up 64-bit box which will allow me to get there relatively easy. If everything fails I will probably try 32-bit but I would like to be able to get some benefits of 64-bit platform - like virtualization. Any help is greatly appreciated.